# How do I pull out a string from an element in selenium python?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium

Heres the HTML of the element that i'm trying to pull a string from

```
<textarea class="FormTextArea__textarea form-control" aria-label="Photo Caption" aria-describedby="photo-caption__help" id="photo-caption" rows="3">Exterior view of villa and pool</textarea>
```

I'm having trouble pulling out "exterior view of villa and pool"

Here is my code responsible for pulling that data

```
caption = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[aria-label='Photo Caption']").get_attribute("textarea")
print(caption)
```

Caption returns "None" every time it chooses a new element

How can I property pull out the string, and return "none" if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your element does not contain a "textarea" attribute, so it would return nothing. Textarea is the tag name of the element. What you want to do is get the text of the element like this:

```
caption = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[aria-label='Photo Caption']").text
print(caption)
```